Issue While Reading and Restoring Query String Values in Document Ready method and AjaxStop method
My Requirement:
I would require it to read query string values as page load and restore in the controls at the same time and to trigger button click event.
Method 1:
First I have tried to fetch and restore query string values in $(document).ready() method.
Issue: Each functions Success method is executing after other code execution. The JSON request is submitting but Success, Complete, Error.
Method 2:
Therefore, I have tried to use $(document).ajaxStop() method.
Issue:
There would be delay binding to database as it runs only after all ajax method get complete. If I forcefully trigger button click event, then it would go under infinite loop.
Code:
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    /* place code to be executed on completion of last outstanding ajax call here */
    ////var $s = jQuery.noConflict();

    /////* Reading Query String Values */
    ////ProductQStr = getParameterByName('product');

    ////// Restore Values of querystring variables
    ////restoreValues(ProductQStr);

    ////// re-Generate query string values
    ////genenrateQueryString();

    ////// Manually trigger submit button click event
    ////// $s('#btnsubmit').trigger('click');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    /* BLOCK */ 
    /* Reading Query String Values */
    ProductQStr = getParameterByName('product');

    // Restore Values of querystring variables
    restoreValues(ProductQStr);    
    
    /* END */
});

function restoreValues(product) {
    var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
    if (product) {
        var arrayofvalue = product.split(',');
        if (arrayofvalue.length > 0) {
            $s('#ddlProduct').val(arrayofvalue);
            var selectedText = arrayofvalue.map(function (id) {
                return $s('#ddlProduct option[value="' + id + '"]').text();
            }).join(', ');

            $s('#ddlProduct').next('.select2').find('.select2-selection__rendered').text(selectedText);
        }
    }
}

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

